# Validate the Date&Time field where time cannit be 00:00

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I got a form where a user can select the date and time. Most users do not really care and do not specify the time therefore leading to time being 00:00

if there a short JavaScript that checks

```
IF **UntilDate** is TIME == 00:00 THEN alert user "specify the date" 
ELSE do not allow to submit the form
```

I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // Here i added code for other functionalities
 });
 //PreSaveAction code to validate
  function PreSaveAction() 
{
     var checkHrs = $('select[class="nf-datepicker-select nf-hours"]').val();
     var checkMin = $('select[class="nf-datepicker-select"]').val();

    if(checkHrs == 00 || checkMin == 00)
    {
       alert('Please specify the time');
       return false;
    }
    else
        {
         return true;
        }
    }
}
 </script>
```

the HTML where I want to implement the java to function.

[image]

Comment: see above, found it on here somewhere and tried to improvise :( I am a noobie in JS

Comment: Never mind, who wants to help somebody who does not know much about javascript ... the forum seems to be only welcome to those who have the advance know-how.

Comment: share your HTML as well